# Write data from custom source to flink in continuous way

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

It is the first time I am working with Apache Flink (1.3.1) and have a question. In more detail I am working with flink-core, flink-cep and flink-streaming library. My application is an Akka ActorSystem what consumes messages from RabbitMQ and various actors handle this messages. In some actors I want to instantiate a `StreamExecutionEnvironment` from Flink and process the incoming messages. Therefore I wrote a custom source class what extends the `RichSourceFunction` class. Everything works find, except one thing: I do not know how to send data to my Flink extension. Here is my setup:

```
public class FlinkExtension {

    private static StreamExecutionEnvironment environment;
    private DataStream<ValueEvent> input;
    private CustomSourceFunction function;

    public FlinkExtension(){

        environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        function = new CustomSourceFunction();
        input = environment.addSource(function);

        PatternStream<ValueEvent> patternStream = CEP.pattern(input, _pattern());

        DataStream<String> warnings = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<ValueEvent, String>() {
            @Override
            public String select(Map<String, List<ValueEvent>> pattern) throws Exception {
                return null; //TODO
            }
        });

        warnings.print();

        try {
            environment.execute();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private Pattern<ValueEvent, ?> _pattern(){

        return Pattern.<ValueEvent>begin("first").where(new SimpleCondition<ValueEvent>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ValueEvent value) throws Exception {
                return value.getValue() > 10;
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendData(ValueEvent value){
        function.sendData(value);
    }
}
```

And this is my custom source function:

```
public class CustomSourceFunction extends RichSourceFunction<ValueEvent> {

    private volatile boolean run = false;
    private SourceContext<ValueEvent> context;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters){
        run = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<ValueEvent> ctx) throws Exception {
        this.context = ctx;

        while (run){

        }
    }

    public void sendData(ValueEvent value){
        this.context.collectWithTimestamp(value, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

So I want to call the method `sendData` in my `FlinkExtension` class from outside to write data in a continuous way to my `FlinkExtension`. Here is my JUnit test what should send data to the extension and then write the data to the `SourceContext`.

```
@Test
public void testSendData(){
    FlinkExtension extension = new FlinkExtension();
    extension.sendData(new ValueEvent(30));
}
```

But if I run the test, nothing happens, the application hangs in the run method of the `CustomSourceFunction`. I also tried to create a new endless thread in the `CustomSourceFunction` run method.

To summarize: Does anybody know how to write data from an application to a Flink instance in a continuous way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink source connectors emit a continuous stream of data by having their run() methods call collect() (or collectWithTimestamp()) inside of the while(run) loop. If you want to study an example, the Apache NiFi source isn't as complex as most; [here's its run method](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/NiFiSource.java#L88).

Comment: There is a slight difference from his question. Looks like he wants to call a send data method from another object. But the NiFi example is creating a transaction inside the source. Which receive messages from that client. A method call is much easier than to create a connection/transaction between object instance. So, is there a way to add message to the source without transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are different object instances of `CustomSourceFunction` being used by the `run` method and the `sendData` method. Hence, the `context` object is not being shared between the methods and adding a new `ValueEvent` does not work.

To fix this, store the object instance used by the `run` method as a static member variable of the `CustomSourceFunction` class.  When you need to create a new `ValueEvent`, invoke the `sendData` method on this same object instance.

See the sample code below

```
package RuleSources;

import Rules.Rule;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DynamicRuleSource extends AlertingRuleSource {
    private static DynamicRuleSource sourceObj;

    private SourceContext<Rule> ctx;

    public static DynamicRuleSource getSourceObject() {
        return sourceObj;
    }

    public void run(SourceContext<Rule> ctx) throws Exception {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        sourceObj = this;
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void addRule(Rule rule) {
        ctx.collect(rule);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
    }
}
```

To add a new rule

```
 public static void addRule(Rule rule) throws Exception {
        AlertingRuleSource sourceObject = DynamicRuleSource.getSourceObject();
        sourceObject.addRule(rule);
    }
```